# WSO2 Fileconnector : get all filenames lcoated at local directory(/home/files)

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

```
WSO2 ESB 5.0 Version
File-Connector 2.* version
```

I have .txt/.csv files located at directory /home/files, now i want all .txt filenames located at directory /home/files. is it possible to get all .txt filenames by using fileconnector 2.* version

if it's not possible by using fileconnector then what is the alternative solution.?

looking forward for help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself. But [file search](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector+Version+2#WorkingwiththeFileConnectorVersion2-search) should work with below pattern, I suppose.

```
<filePattern>*.txt</filePattern>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the file search operation.

```
{
 "source":" /home/files",
 "filePattern":".*\.txt"
 }
```